# Undefined Variable: Results on Line 28

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm doing a query from my database via MySQLi, and I'm getting the following error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: results in C:\xampp\htdocs\Test Website\Includes\databaseconnect.php on line 25

I've looked over my code, and I've looked over the code on my tutorial and they're identical.  Here's my tutorial: https://youtu.be/Z0iQMJ4S0WI?t=10m23s.  It starts at 10:23 pause it there and see the code.

Here's my code:

```
$dbServername = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "root";
$dbPassword = "";
$dbName = "phplessons";

$conn = new mysqli($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

if ($conn->connect_errno) {
  printf("Connection failed %s\n", $conn->connect_error);
  exit();
}

$id = 8;
$stmt = $conn->prepare("Select * FROM posts WHERE ID=?");
$stmt->bind_param("d", $id);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
  $results[] = $row;
}

print_r($results);

?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd say it's probably because your query failed. What does `mysqli_error($conn)` return? and why the `d` for a double? Is the column type a double or int?

Comment: plus `fetch_object()` may not be what you want to use here and that also could be failing http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php

Comment: Wow, that's it.  I forgot I did a query to delete the information from my table... can you put this as an answer so I can select it?

Comment: you mean about the `d` rather than an `i`? or the other comment?

Comment: Both, actually.  It was an `int`, but it was also the fact that there was no info in the table.

Comment: @ThomasHutton I posted a community wiki answer that you can mark off.

Comment: @mickmackusa if you mean by using the undefined variable/index dupe, you'd be wrong. This is a different case entirely.

Comment: @mickmackusa I did double check it all, my problem was that I put an integer in my column and the tutor put a double.  So I was looking at the wrong data type.

Comment: @mickmackusa about your *"Fredii doesn't need the rep points, he's got heaps."* this isn't about having more rep points or wanting more, it's how things work, it's the fact of the matter. If you were at my level of points, you'd of most likely have submitted one and not a wiki neither. But at the risk of a probable downvote, I decided to post a wiki answer, and at the same time, I solved it in comments, which is what I do at times for questions like these where it could have been voted to close as a probable typo. The OP invited me to post an answer and I did.

Comment: @mickmackusa I noticed you deleted your comments. [Your last one](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/80708303?noredirect=1) about the closest you could find was automatically deleted since I used it to close the question. Thanks for finding that link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing that the question was solved in comments, stating that their column type was an `int` rather than a double, the `d` should have been an `i`.